# Android cannot find ndk method impementation

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

#### No implementation issue

I'm using bridge between C++ and Java on Android, for scanning files in android
so i have question, i have error with

```
No implementation found for void com.example.Scanner.scan(java.lang.String) (tried Java_com_example_Scanner_scan and Java_com_example_Scanner_scan__Ljava_lang_String_2)
```

#### Scanner file source

```
public class Scanner extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        scan("sdcard/");
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    native void scan(String path);

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("scanner");
    }
```

}

#### scanner.cpp

```
void Java_com_example_Scanner_scan(JNIEnv* env, jclass cls, jstring path)
{
    mJNI = env;
    mObject = cls;

    const char *scan_path = mJNI->GetStringUTFChars(path, 0);

    scan(string(scan_path));

    // Release string IMPORTANT For Java & C++
    mJNI->ReleaseStringUTFChars(path, scan_path);
}
```

Comment: You may need to declare these `extern "C"` to avoid name mangling by the C++ compiler.  You can use the ndk-objdump on the .so files to see if the names are plain or decorated by the mangling algorithm.  You should also check the log to be sure that your native library has actually been found and loaded.

Comment: So the problem is solved?  If so we should probably close this as a duplicate of one of the other questions on that particular issue.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot JNIexport and JNIcall.
This is how it should look like:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_ClassName_MethodName
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
    /*Implement Native Method Here*/
}
```

So for you it should be:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_Scanner_scan(JNIEnv* env, jclass cls, jstring path)
{
//do you things
}
```

You can find some nice information here: [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface)